# Scrape table using webscaper

Tags: web-scraping, html-table

I am trying to scrape a table from test sites of webscaper but I am not able to. Please tell me next steps. link of website:https://webscraper.io/test-sites/tablesI am attaching a photograph.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Next step, select which web scrap library(or framework) is best for you.

If use javascript based (React, Angular, node.js), `Axios and Cheerio` or `Puppeteer`

If use python, `Scrapy` or `BeautifulSoup`

If use Java, `Jsoup` or `HTMLUnit`

Demo for your table scrapping by `Puppeteer`

#1  install node.js into your PC

```
https://nodejs.org/en/download/
```

#2 copy this code and save with 'get-table.js`

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function getData(url) {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);

        titles = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr td"),
                title => title.innerText.trim());
        });

        await browser.close();
        return Promise.resolve(titles);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

getData('https://webscraper.io/test-sites/tables')
    .then((titles) => {
        console.log(titles);
    })
```

#3 install `puppeteer` and run your code

```
npm install puppeteer
node get-table.js
```

#4 Get result for scrapping

```json
$ node get-table.js
[
  '1', 'Mark',  'Otto',     '@mdo',
  '2', 'Jacob', 'Thornton', '@fat',
  '3', 'Larry', 'the Bird', '@twitter',
  '4', 'Harry', 'Potter',   '@hp',
  '5', 'John',  'Snow',     '@dunno',
  '6', 'Tim',   'Bean',     '@timbean',
  '1', 'Mark',  'Otto',     '@mdo',
  '2', 'Jacob', 'Thornton', '@fat',
  '3', 'Larry', 'the Bird', '@twitter',
  '-', '-',     '-',        '-',
  '1', 'Mark',  'Otto',     '@mdo',
  '2', 'Jacob', 'Thornton', '@fat',
  '3', 'Larry', 'the Bird', '@twitter'
]
```